# How must I create a custom activity that can be used to drag other activities in?

Tags: .net-3.5, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I created a workflow activity which I want to reuse in my sequenceworkflow as a reusable block.

The problem I'm having, that I cannot at child activities in my block. I'm getting locks on the custom activity.

This should be possible, right?

```
 [Designer(typeof(SequentialActivityDesigner), typeof(IDesigner))]
public partial class CheckTypeProcesActivity : SequenceActivity
{
    public static DependencyProperty ProcesTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ProcesType", typeof(Enums.ProcesType), typeof(CheckTypeProcesActivity));

    public CheckTypeProcesActivity()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CanModifyActivities = true;

    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Parameters")]
    public Enums.ProcesType ProcesType
    {
        get { return (Enums.ProcesType)GetValue(ProcesTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ProcesTypeProperty, value); }
    }
}
```